# Need Help understanding a Solution to an opencourseware question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to do MIT 6.042J. I am trying to do the recitation 12 problem which is provided in the following link

[enter link description here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/0500ce233605828a0c556c282353e0af_MIT6_042JF10_rec12_sol.pdf)

what I cant understand is how was the equation

$$  c_h = [c_1 + (c_1 + 1) + · · · + (c_1 + (h − 1))] /h$$

regrouped into

$$ c_h = [hc_1 + (1 + 2 + · · · + (h − 1))] /h$$

which further changed to

$$[hc_1 + h(h − 1)/2] /h$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: $c+c=2c$. Also note that $c+c+c=3c$.

Comment: Also note that $$\sum_{i=1}^{h-1} (i) = \frac{(h-1)h}{2}.$$

Comment: still dont get it, opening left side of the . . . gives 2c + 1 and the right side of . . . gives c + h -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by regrouping all the $c_1$'s together and separating the constants

$c_h = \frac{[(c_1 + \dots + c_1) + (1 + 2 + \dots + (h-1))]}{h}$.

Notice that there are $h$ number of $c_1$'s. This implies that

$c_h = \frac{[(h \cdot c_1)+(1 + 2 + \dots + (h-1))]}{h}$.

The reason for this goes back to the very definition of multiplication, i.e., it is repeated addition of a quantity.

Notice that the other part of the numerator is the sum of $(h-1)$ natural numbers. Therefore, by using the formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, we get the following

$c_h = \frac{(hc_1 + \frac{h(h-1)}{2})}{h}$,

which is the equation where you ended your question.

This further simplifies to

$c_h = \frac{2c_1 + (h-1)}{2}$.

Finally, we get

$c_h = c_1 + \frac{(h-1)}{2}$.